# Any idea how can I make 3 different form work independently in one page in django?

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-templates

So I am using 3 forms in one page and want those forms to be independent. But don't know how to approach this.

I have 3 forms
ProfileUpdateForm
ProfileUpdateFormm
ProfileUpdateFormb
(sorry for the terrible naming)

here is the code in my views.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        m_form = ProfileUpdateFormm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        b_form = ProfileUpdateFormb(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
        if m_form.is_valid():
            m_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
        if b_form.is_valid():
            b_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    context={'p_form': p_form,'m_form': m_form,'b_form': b_form}
    return render(request, 'app/profile_form.html',context )
```

But its throwing this error
UnboundLocalError at /home/profile/ local variable 'p_form' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `else` clause that handles GET requests:

```py
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        m_form = ProfileUpdateFormm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        b_form = ProfileUpdateFormb(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
        if m_form.is_valid():
            m_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
        if b_form.is_valid():
            b_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    else:  # In case the request is GET
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        m_form = ProfileUpdateFormm(instance=request.user.profile)
        b_form = ProfileUpdateFormb(instance=request.user.profile)
    context={'p_form': p_form,'m_form': m_form,'b_form': b_form}
    return render(request, 'app/profile_form.html',context )
```